# Is this possible to make something like this (a complex shaped clipping path) in CSS 3?

Tags: html, css

An example:

[image]

Is this possible to make something like this in CSS only?

I want to make 2 divs.

1. That will be a circle without background and border.
2. Div that will have a background

I want to make the point 1. clip the background from point 2.

That way I will be able to rotate the background, and have a nice feel of moving background.

Comment: You can do this, just do a search with " css masking " and you'll find  a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure css animations plus shape.

The only downside to this is the middle cut out of the circle. It can not be transparent so the center color has to match the background's color. (You can set the background of the inner circle to an image or whatever suits your needs but it won't be transparent.)

Here is the css:

```
.circ {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url("http://www.freefever.com/stock/commercial-wallpapers-abstract-colored-texture-backgroundand-photo-high.jpg");
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: Spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.circ:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@-webkit-keyframes Spin {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 100%;  
    }
}
```

Finally, the live fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEy6D/1/)

---

**Updated** fiddle(forgot to include other browser prefixes): [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEy6D/3/)

One thing I suggest it to make a sepreate css file for the animations, due to keyframes they take up a lot of space in your files. Something like animations.css so your normal styles can be isolated on the main css file.

If you need the center to be responsive to what is behind it then I suggest theChrisMarsh's answer.

Comment: Your solution is best - by best I mean it's most simple of the rest solutions. Thank You for that - I will use it : )

Comment: No problem and best of luck mate. I do suggest using theChrisMarsh's answer if you run into problems with the inner circle though.

Answer (score 8):

You can clip an element with a compound SVG object. You only need 1 div with this css.

```
.doughnut-clipping { clip-path: url(#doughnut-path); }
```

In additional you need and SVG with the doughnut shape defined.

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='400' height='400'> 
  <clipPath id='doughnut-path'> 
    <path d='M0,200 A200,200 0,1,1 400,200 A200,200 0,1,1 0,200 z 
           M100,200 A100,100 0,1,1 300,200 A100,100 0,1,1 100,200 z' 
           clip-rule='evenodd'/> 
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've never heard of [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) before. pretty neat solution though! nice one.

Comment: This approach allows whatever is underneath the center of the doughnut to show through.

Answer (score 0):

If you get inspired you could try using HTML5 canvas to draw an element like this completely : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp
http://davidwalsh.name/canvas-demos

Answer (score 0):

About the 2 divs solutions, is this enough ?

http://jsfiddle.net/bvW6m/

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.outter{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ededed;
}
.inner{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

You should give us what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

you could as well use background, fied , border-radius and animation for the rotation

```
html, span {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/abstract/1) no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
}
/* opacity and displayto align middle used for demo */
html {display:table;height:100%;width:100%;}
body {display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
div, span {border-radius:100%;animation:rot 5s linear infinite;transform:rotate(0deg);}
div {width:40%;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/abstract/2)  center;
  background-size:20%;
  opacity:0.8;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:5px 0 5px, 5px 0 5px inset
    }
div:before {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  content:'';
}
span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:40%;
  padding-top:40%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px, 0 0 5px inset;
  background-size:1000%;
  animation-direction:reverse;
}
@keyframes rot {
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```
 <div class="deco">
   <span></span>
 </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cbwyf

Comment: to see through , you could use box-shadow: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fflbr if have the patience to draw image from multiple shadows

Comment: Thanks, Your solution is pretty what I want. But in Your example on Opera the animation is not working.

Comment: did you use the prefix for the animation ? (dowloading opera at this time ) demo updated with prefix http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cbwyf